# How can I make an animation with timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, console

I wanted to make a method that took a timer and ascii text and changed the text when the timer hit 1 second and back again when the timer hits 2. I created this timer but didn't know how to use it to do that method. Can anyone help?

```cs
public void TimePassed()
{
    Timer t1 = new Timer(1000);
    t1.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;

    t1.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();

    t1.Stop();
}

public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timerPlayerOneAnimation++;
    Console.WriteLine(timerPlayerOneAnimation + " " + DateTime.Now);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried in `Timer_Elapsed` to just check the timer's time and if it's greater than two reverse the animation? Something like `if(sender is Timer timerObj) if(timerObj.ElapsedTime >= 2000) // do something`

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if your counter is even or odd?

```
public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // possibly set the cursor position?
    Console.SetCursorPosition(someRow, someColumn);

    timerPlayerOneAnimation++;
    if (timerPlayerOneAnimation % 2 == 0) {
        // Display one thing
    }
    else {
        // Display something else
    }        
}
```